# Is the a way in which I can integrate whatsApp Order in my django ecommerce website

Tags: django

Am creating a django ecommerce website and I want to add an option where users can checkout through whatsapp. I want them to be able to send all their orders to the admin's whatsapp. Anyone who can help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can use a service like [twilio](https://www.twilio.com/whatsapp) to build a whatsapp bot in python to receive and send messages via a *registered* business account on whatsapp.
2. You will need to setup a webhook (endpoint to listen on) in your django app to receive the incoming messages.
3. A pattern could be made to allow for a data flow like:

```
user sends message on whatsapp -> twilio sends it to your webhook -> you parse the message and finally call a function like `create_order()` in your django app.
```

This [tutorial](https://www.twilio.com/docs/whatsapp/tutorial/send-and-receive-media-messages-whatsapp-python?code-sample=code-reply-with-media-to-incoming-whatsapp-messages&code-language=Python&code-sdk-version=default) might help you.